# .htacess file to get rid of index.php but keep everything after

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, web

My directory structure in apache is as follows:

```
turkr/
     public_html/
                api/
                index.php
                .htacess
```

`index.php` is my front controller for my APIs, so every endpoint should be directed to this file. So far I've accomplished this with this in my `api/.htacess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).php/$ /~turk/api/$1.php [R=301,L]
```

However, instead of using `www.example.com/~turkr/api/index.php/someTable`, I'd like to remove the `index.php` and so that it is a bit cleaner:

```
www.example.com/~turkr/api/someTable
```

I'm new to `.htaccess` files so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `/~turkr/api/index.php/someTable` - is this the URL you are currently requesting? (That wouldn't require any rewriting in order to pass the information as path-info to your script?) The directive you posted doesn't appear to be doing anything - that really makes sense - currently? The rule also uses `~turk`, not `~turkr`?

Comment: The rule should be using ~turkr, sorry! Are you saying it isn't doing anything?

Comment: If the URL as stated is the URL you are currently requesting then yes, that rule is not doing anything. What do you think that rule is doing? Also, the `/~turkr` part of the URL looks like an Apache per-user web directory - is that necessary here? (It doesn't match your directory structure.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ api/index.php [R=301,L]
```

And, if it's just a typo. Your file must be named `.htaccess`.